# angular bracket

Tags: vectors

For my Calculus III class, the textbook uses angular brackets rather than parenthesis to represent vectors, e.g. $a=\langle a_1,a_2,a_3\rangle$

Though from what I have read and understood, the angular brackets represent the inner product, e.g. $\langle a,b\rangle=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$

How does the angular bracket represent vectors in a geometric space?

Comment: Notation is not completely standardized. Some people use angle brackets, some people use hard brackets, some people use parentheses. Context matters.

Comment: It's a matter of choice of notation.